# 3D touch/Force touch implementation

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

How can we implement 3D touch to check if the user taps on `UIView` or force touch on `UIView`?

Is there a way to do this with `UIGestureRecognize` or only with `UITouch`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it without a designated gesture recognizer. You do not need to adjust the touchesEnded and touchesBegan method, but simply the touchesMoved to obtain the correct values. getting the force of a uitouch from began/ended will return weird values.

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

CGFloat maximumPossibleForce = touch.maximumPossibleForce;
CGFloat force = touch.force;
CGFloat normalizedForce = force/maximumPossibleForce;
```

then, set a force threshold and compare the normalizedForce to this threshold (0.75 seems fine for me).

Answer (score 9):

The 3D Touch properties [are available on `UITouch` objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html).

You can get these touches by overriding a `UIView`'s `touchesBegan:` and `touchesMoved:` methods. Not sure what you see in `touchesEnded:` yet.

If you're willing to create new gesture recognizers, you have full access to the `UITouch`es as exposed in `UIGestureRecognizerSubclass`.

I'm not sure how you could use the 3D touch properties in a traditional `UIGestureRecognizer`. Maybe via the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol's `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` method.

Comment: I want to check if the user tap on UIView or force touch on UIView

Comment: `UITapGestureRecognizer` hasn't been updated for 3D Touch, so you would have to make your own `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass or subclass the views and handle `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved`.

Comment: If a touch doesn't move but it's force changes does `touchesMoved:` get called?

Answer (score 9):

With Swift 4.2 and iOS 12, a possible way to solve your problem is to create a custom subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer` that handles Force Touch and add it to your view next to a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. The following complete code shows how to implement it:

*ViewController.swift*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let redView = UIView()
    lazy var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler))
    lazy var forceTouchGestureRecognizer = ForceTouchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(forceTouchHandler))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        redView.backgroundColor = .red    
        redView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

        view.addSubview(redView)
        redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        redView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        redView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.available {
            redView.addGestureRecognizer(forceTouchGestureRecognizer)
        } else  {
            // When force touch is not available, remove force touch gesture recognizer.
            // Also implement a fallback if necessary (e.g. a long press gesture recognizer)
            redView.removeGestureRecognizer(forceTouchGestureRecognizer)
        }
    }

    @objc func tapHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Tap triggered")
    }

    @objc func forceTouchHandler(_ sender: ForceTouchGestureRecognizer) {
        UINotificationFeedbackGenerator().notificationOccurred(.success)
        print("Force touch triggered")
    }

}
```

*ForceTouchGestureRecognizer.swift*

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
final class ForceTouchGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    private let threshold: CGFloat = 0.75

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if let touch = touches.first {
            handleTouch(touch)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        if let touch = touches.first {
            handleTouch(touch)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        state = UIGestureRecognizer.State.failed
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        state = UIGestureRecognizer.State.failed
    }

    private func handleTouch(_ touch: UITouch) {
        guard touch.force != 0 && touch.maximumPossibleForce != 0 else { return }

        if touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce >= threshold {
            state = UIGestureRecognizer.State.recognized
        }
    }

}
```

---

Sources:

- [GitHub / FlexMonkey - DeepPressGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/DeepPressGestureRecognizer)
- [GitHub / ashleymills - ForceTouchGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/ashleymills/ForceTouchGestureRecognizer.swift/blob/master/ForceTouchGestureRecognizer.swift)
- [Apple Developer Documentation - Implementing a Discrete Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer/implementing_a_discrete_gesture_recognizer)

Answer (score 7):

I created a UIGestureRecognizer that emulates the behavior of the Apple Mail app. Upon 3D touch, it starts with a short single pulse vibrate and then an optional secondary action (hardTarget) and pulse called by hard pressing shortly after the initial press.

Adapted from https://github.com/FlexMonkey/DeepPressGestureRecognizer

Changes:

- 3D touch vibrate pulses like iOS system behavior
- touch must come up for it to end, like Apple mail app
- threshold defaults to system default level
- hard touch triggers hardAction call like mail app

**Note: I added the undocumented system sound k_PeakSoundID, but feel free to turn that off if you are uncomfortable using a constant beyond the documented range**. I have been using system sounds with undisclosed constants for years, but you are welcomed to turn off the vibration pulses using the vibrateOnDeepPress property.

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass
import AudioToolbox

class DeepPressGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    var vibrateOnDeepPress = true
    var threshold: CGFloat = 0.75
    var hardTriggerMinTime: TimeInterval = 0.5

    var onDeepPress: (() -> Void)?

    private var deepPressed: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if (deepPressed && deepPressed != oldValue) {
                onDeepPress?()
            }
        }
    }

    private var deepPressedAt: TimeInterval = 0
    private var k_PeakSoundID: UInt32 = 1519
    private var hardAction: Selector?
    private var target: AnyObject?

    required init(target: AnyObject?, action: Selector, hardAction: Selector? = nil, threshold: CGFloat = 0.75) {
        self.target = target
        self.hardAction = hardAction
        self.threshold = threshold

        super.init(target: target, action: action)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            handle(touch: touch)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            handle(touch: touch)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        state = deepPressed ? UIGestureRecognizerState.ended : UIGestureRecognizerState.failed
        deepPressed = false
    }

    private func handle(touch: UITouch) {
        guard let _ = view, touch.force != 0 && touch.maximumPossibleForce != 0 else {
            return
        }

        let forcePercentage = (touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce)
        let currentTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        if !deepPressed && forcePercentage >= threshold {
            state = UIGestureRecognizerState.began

            if vibrateOnDeepPress {
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(k_PeakSoundID)
            }

            deepPressedAt = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
            deepPressed = true

        } else if deepPressed && forcePercentage <= 0 {
            endGesture()

        } else if deepPressed && currentTime - deepPressedAt > hardTriggerMinTime && forcePercentage == 1.0 {
            endGesture()

            if vibrateOnDeepPress {
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(k_PeakSoundID)
            }

            //fire hard press
            if let hardAction = self.hardAction, let target = self.target {
                _ = target.perform(hardAction, with: self)
            }
        }
    }

    func endGesture() {
        state = UIGestureRecognizerState.ended
        deepPressed = false
    }
}

// MARK: DeepPressable protocol extension
protocol DeepPressable {
    var gestureRecognizers: [UIGestureRecognizer]? {get set}

    func addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
    func removeGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)

    func setDeepPressAction(target: AnyObject, action: Selector)
    func removeDeepPressAction()
}

extension DeepPressable {

    func setDeepPressAction(target: AnyObject, action: Selector) {
        let deepPressGestureRecognizer = DeepPressGestureRecognizer(target: target, action: action, threshold: 0.75)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: deepPressGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func removeDeepPressAction() {
        guard let gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers else { return }

        for recogniser in gestureRecognizers where recogniser is DeepPressGestureRecognizer {
            removeGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: recogniser)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably an architectural mistake to put vibration code in the recognizer.

Comment: Only working on iOS 15, Not working on previous iOS version like 14, 13, 12. ....

Answer (score 6):

The way I am doing this is to use a combination of a [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html) (provided by Apple) and a [DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/foggzilla/DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer) (provided by me).

The `DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer` is nice because it provides continuous updates about the pressure changes so you can do things like augment the view as the user varies their pressure on it, as opposed to a single event. If you just want a single event you can ignore eveything in the `DFContinuousForceTouchDelegate` except the `- (void) forceTouchRecognized` callback.

https://github.com/foggzilla/DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer

You can download this and run the sample app on a device that supports force press to see how it feels.

In your `UIViewController` implement the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _forceTouchRecognizer = [[DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    _forceTouchRecognizer.forceTouchDelegate = self;

    //here to demonstrate how this works alonside a tap gesture recognizer
    _tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];

    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:_tapGestureRecognizer];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:_forceTouchRecognizer];
}
```

implement selector for tap gesture

```
#pragma UITapGestureRecognizer selector

- (void)tapped:(id)sender {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tap" message:@"YEAH!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    });
}
```

Implement the delegate protocol for force touch:

```
#pragma DFContinuousForceTouchDelegate

- (void)forceTouchRecognized:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Force Touch" message:@"YEAH!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    });
}

- (void)forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer didStartWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce {
    CGFloat transformDelta = 1.0f + ((force/maxForce) / 3.0f);
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(transformDelta, transformDelta);
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer didMoveWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce {
    CGFloat transformDelta = 1.0f + ((force/maxForce) / 3.0f);
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(transformDelta, transformDelta);
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer didCancelWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce  {
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer didEndWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce  {
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)forceTouchDidTimeout:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Note that this will only be useful on a device that supports force touch.

Also you should not add the `DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer` to a view if are you running on iOS 8 or under since it uses the new `force` property on `UITouch` only available in iOS 9.

If you add this on iOS 8 it will crash, so conditionally add this recognizer based on what iOS version you are running on if you are supporting versions older than iOS 9.

Comment: Wow thanks! Can you convert your answer to Swift 2.0? And my app support iOS 8 - 9 so I don't need to add DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer to view